# Magento API calling using HTML and javascript

Tags: api, javascript, rest-api, html

I'm new to Magento and I'm developing a PhoneGap app using HTML5, CSS and Javascript. I searched many places and read Magento documentations, but couldn't get any example for authenticating, calling, getting results from the Magento APIs using javascript. I came to know that token-based authentications is needed and REST APIs are suitable for my purpose. Maily I have the following doubts.

- What are the settings I have to do in admin panel of Magento for accessing APIs.
- How to authenticate to Magento APIs in a page using HTML5 and Javascript.
- What are the APIs provided by Magento and how to call them in a page using HTML5 and Javascript.

Comment: Magento 1 or Magento 2?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: did you find any solution on this ? @ shree

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I only gave u a wiki with events of API of magento [here](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Magento+1.x+Events+Reference)

Comment: I'm a novice in this field. It would be better if I get any examples of solutions for above mentioned issues.